# One proof about isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that vec: $R^{m\times n}$ →$R^{mn}$, dened on the basis {$e^{ij}$} by
$$
e^{ij}\to e^{(j-1)m+i}
$$
and extended linearly, is an isomorphism.

I think it has been linear already. So, I need to prove there is a "$vec^{-1}$" which can do the opposite. But really have no idea.

Comment: What is $e^{ij}$? And yes, the linear extension of the given basis map is indeed linear.

Comment: Form the matrix of the linear transformation. Show that it's invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that $e_{ij}$ is the matrix with $ij$th entry equal to 1 and 0 elsewhere. This is certainly a basis for the real vector space of $m \times n$ matrices. I assume you mean $R = \mathbb R$, but the same holds true for any ring, by replacing "vector space" with "free module". Ignore that last sentence if you don't know ring theory. The general fact that is essential here is that for vector spaces $V$ and $W$ and a basis $S \subseteq V$, a linear map $V \longrightarrow W$ is totally and uniquely determined by where $S$ is sent. By this, I mean that any choice of where you send the elements of $S$ induces a linear map $V \longrightarrow W$ and any two linear maps that agree on $S$ are the same.

Put a little more formally, let $A$ be the set of maps $S \longrightarrow W$ and let $B$ be the set of all linear maps $V \longrightarrow W$. What I said above can be simplified as saying that the map $B \longrightarrow A$ via $f \mapsto f|_S$ is a bijection. The inverse is as you described, you extend the map $S \longrightarrow W$ linearly.

So as you say, you now want a map $\mathbb R^{mn} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ which is a two sided inverse to the map you've given. By what I just said above, it suffices to take a basis of $\mathbb R^{mn}$ and decide where those elements map. Furthermore, to check that these are inverses it would suffice to check that they restrict to inverses on the bases.

The question now is what basis of $\mathbb R^{mn}$ do you take and where do you send them? I recommend you think about this a bit, as getting used to this idea of understanding maps of vector spaces from what they do to a basis is critical to linear algebra. I'll put the answer in a spoiler below.

> So the natural choice of basis for $\mathbb R^{mn}$ is, of course, the standard basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_{mn}\}$. Let $B_1 = \{e_{ij}\}$ and $B_2 = \{e_1, \dots e_{mn}\}$ the respective bases. You've given me a map $f: B_1 \longrightarrow B_2$. Suppose that this map is a bijection, ie invertible. Then I have a map $f^{-1}: B_2 \longrightarrow B_1$. If we compose this with the inclusion map $B_1 \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, we get a map $B_2 \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. As discussed above, this extends uniquely to a linear map $T: \mathbb R^{mn} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m \times n}$. I claim now that $vec$ and $T$ are inverse to each other. Indeed, consider $T \circ vec$. As I said above, two linear maps that agree on a basis are the same, so to prove that $T \circ vec = id$, I only have to check that $T \circ vec$ agrees with the identity on a basis, such as $B_1$. Indeed, $T(vec(e_{ij})) = T(f(e_{ij}))$. As $T$ extends $f^{-1}$ by definition, that equals $f^{-1}(f(e_{ij})) = e_{ij}$. Thus, $T \circ vec$ agrees with the identity on the basis $B_1$, so as $T \circ vec$ and $id$ are linear, they are equal. A symmetric argument will show that $vec \circ T = id$, so $T = vec^{-1}$. Thus, it suffices to prove that $f: B_1 \longrightarrow B_2$ is indeed a bijection. I'll leave this part as an exercise for you.